# Autocomplete console text

Tags: java, sqlite, autocomplete, console-application

I need to create a Java console application that make suggestions for the name of food to the user. This information will be fetched from `sqlite` database file. User will write text and program will whispering the names of items. When user want to complete the text he press the TAB key and application will get next item. 
I have already all databases items recorded at ArrayList.

[My main idea(without everything except for the top text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzEaA.gif)

Part of code -
Main class

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Food> foodList= DatabaseServices.loadAllFood();
    ArrayList<String> foodNameList=new ArrayList();
    String nameFood;

    while (condition) {//when I have all recipe names
      //some code
      nameFood=sc.nextLine();
      foodNameList(nameFood);
    }
```

*Edit:*

DatabaseServices class

```
public ArrayList<food> loadAllFood() {//fetch data and sort them
        ArrayList<food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM foods ";
            ResultSet data = MyDatabaseConnection.executeQuery(SQL);


            do {
                Food food= new Food(data.getInt("food_id"),
                        data.getString("nfood_nazev"),
                        data.getInt("food_bilkoviny"),
                        data.getInt("food_sacharidy"),
                        data.getInt("food_tuky"));
                foodList .add(potravina);
            } while (data.next());

            Collections.sort(foodList );

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    return foodList;
    }
```

Is there some easy way to do that???

Comment: 1) fetch the data 2) sort them 3) onChange of the textbox, binary search the list for the closest match that is a superstring of the input (if any) 4) if any, show it in the suggestion

Comment: 1),2) done 3) It shouldn't be textbox, but jconsole. I explained it badly :/. The list search I'd like to use foreach and condition if something like that string.( string+".*" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli) Java command line parsing library recently added autocomplete functionality.

This is based on generating a bash autocompletion script. Once users source the completion script, the bash shell will show possible completions for the command, subcommand, or option (in Windows you can use Cygwin or Babun). If you look at the picocli source code, you can see how the list of possible completion option values is generated for Java enums.

You can modify this to generate a list of possible completion options from the database, generate a new completion script, and source this script before running your command.

You may also like how the library enables you to use ANSI colors and styles in the usage help message.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the author and therefore biased.*

Answer (score 0):

As @DiegoMartinoia said in his comment you can do this on a key down:

1. search on the text (if there are more then 3 chars because of
   performance)
2. sort alphabetical
3. show the top 5-ish

Answer (score 0):

as said before, do those five steps. 
But to autocomplete command in console application you could use [Jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) library. Its autocopletion thru tabulator.

And for last, you would not be using Jconsole, if you are not using JMX mBeans, but thats just for information.(Of course if you are planning to do it with JMX then this is irrevelant)